# How to set a GRPC named parameter with name 'from'?

Tags: python, grpc

The GRPC request object to send emails expects to pass 'from' as the sender's email address.

Here is the definition part of `SendEmailRequest` in .proto file

```
    message SendEmailRequest {
      ...
      Address from = 6;
    }
```

So it should be instantiated like this:

```
    email_pb2.SendEmailRequest(from="no-reply@example.com", ...)
```

but Python is not happy with that keyword, any tricks to pass that named parameter?

Comment: What errors are you receiving? You should include it in the post

Answer (score 0):

```py
import email_pb2

send_email_request = email_pb2.SendEmailRequest()

obj = getattr(send_email_request, "from")

# E.g.
obj.street = "Main St"

print(send_email_request.SerializeToString())
```

[Names which conflict with Python keywords](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#keyword-conflicts)